# Is there an easy way to change bash suggestions?

Tags: bash, autocomplete

I've noticed that some console commands (like sudo or xargs) are using different kind of suggestions when I press Tab (they suggest programs instead of files).

Is there a way to mimic that kind of behavior for self written bash script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour is called "Programmable Completion". You can customize it. See `man bash` for details.